# Pigeon issue calculate the whole "persons"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have done an exercise but I am not sure for the result. Could you help me with it if it right or wrong? The exercise:

> I have a university and I have students ages $18$ to $25$.  At least how many people should be in a trip to ensure there will be at least $10$ persons with the same age and the same sex (men and women).

What I did was $\frac x{20} =10$ so $x=10 \cdot 20 = 200$. $x$ is the whole persons  and I divide by $20$ because $10$ women and $10$ men. Am I right?  Wrong? What?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 8 age groups and two sexes.

There can be at most 9 in each group without reaching the desired position.

Therefore you must have $8\times2\times9+1=145$ people.

Comment: So my answer is wrong completely?

Comment: @m.s I am not sure why you divided by 20 the first place, but in these types of problems find the "pigeonholes" and then apply pigeonhole principle is almost always the right way to go.

Comment: Because 10 men and 10 women so will be 20 for sure

Comment: No. It should be 18. You want to consider the worst case, where 9 men and 9 women are selected in each age group. And the extra person will be enough to satisfy the condition.